# Почему получаю {Path} was unexpected at this time в command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

Пытаюсь создать папку, если ее еще не существует командой:

```
IF NOT EXISTS "{path}" DO mkdir "{path}"
```

Вместо {path} абсолютный путь к папке. Получаю ошибку:

> "{path}" was unexpected at this time.

Почему получаю такую ошибку? Чего не хватает в команде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильная команда

```
IF NOT EXIST "{path}" mkdir "{path}"
```